# Magento 2.3 Site Unwanted Redirect

Tags: magento2.3, php, redirect, htaccess

My Magento 2.3 site is redirecting and I am unsure why. When I access the domain, it redirects to domain.com/Industrial%20Cleaning%20Products. I have done the following to try and rectify the issue:

- Checked core_config tables
- Set both base urls and secure urls through the admin panel
- Set both base urls and sercure urls through the command line
- Cleaned/flushed cache
- Deleted all contents in the cache folders

Looking for any help as to where I should look/how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: You should check into your URL Rewrites to ensure there is nothing setup that is causing the redirect to this specific page.

Comment: @AKKAweb Nothing in the redirects or in the database that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Really weird..
Maybe check the config.php file. Is possible that there is a value overwriting your DB values. Just a suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

My customer installed a module that forced the user to log in before seeing the site. The idiots typed in the wrong slug... My apologies all.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer to close the post :)

Answer (score 1):

Check **rewrite** related sections of **.htaccess** file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/184722)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.